# Facing error while getting value of dynamically created textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have created a dynamic textbox but unable to fetch its value on runtime. it shows something else.

**`code`**

```
    var UL = document.createElement('ul');
    var Li = document.createElement('li');
    var A4 = document.createElement('input');
    A4.type = 'text';
    A4.setAttribute('id', 'current_page');
    A4.value = list.length;
    A4.setAttribute('style', 'width:30px;height:26px;text-align:center;position:relative;left:35px');
    Li.appendChild(A4);
    UL.appendChild(Li);
```

**`script`**

```
var va = $('#current_page').val;
        alert(va);
```

Comment: What's the error? Where do you try to fetch it's value?

Comment: if you're using jquery, its val() not val

Comment: `val()` is a method. That _something else_ is the `.val()` function's body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you're using JavaScript for everything else, save the jQuery for another day:

```
var va = document.getElementById('current_page').value;
```

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you need to use .val(); instead of .val;

```
var va = $('#current_page').val();
        alert(va);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't look like you're ever appending anything to the document.
2. You need to use `$('#current_page').val();` to get the value

For future reference can check if your selectors are finding anything using:

```
console.log($('#current_page'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) in jQuery and it is a function

```
var val = $('#current_page').val();
alert(val);
```

Using Native JavaScript, You can use [**document.getElementById**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)

```
alert(document.getElementById('current_page').value)
```